# Sort list using dictionary key values

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting

Lets say i have a list to sort of

```
list_values = ['key3', 'key0', 'key1', 'key4', 'key2']
```

And a order dict of

```
ordered_dict = OrderedDict([('key4', 0), ('key1', 1), ('key2', 2), ('key0', 3), ('key3', 4)])
```

How can i sort the `list_values` using the `ordered_dict` key accordingly?

i.e:- `sorted_list = ['key4', 'key1', 'key2', 'key0', 'key3']`

**EDIT:** Since almost all of the answers solves the problem, what is the most suitable and perfect pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: Re:Edit. Generally, non-lambda solutions are preferred. I could go into a breakdown of each solution, but it would be more convincing for you if you could just time the solutions on your data and accept the fastest one.

Comment: oh, yeah sure..

Comment: Do note that `list.sort` is an in-place method, which is faster but also sorts the data in-place, so make sure to reset the list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `list.sort`, passing a custom `key`:

```
list_values.sort(key=ordered_dict.get)    
list_values
# ['key4', 'key1', 'key2', 'key0', 'key3']
```

---

Alternatively, the non-in-place version is done using,

```
sorted(list_values, key=ordered_dict.get)
# ['key4', 'key1', 'key2', 'key0', 'key3']
```

Comment: Well, this is the best answer so far. btw, in my case i will go with non-in-place option since i want to store the returned sorted list. Thank you @coldspeed

Answer (score 1):

If we assume that list is subset of dict:

```
list_values = ['key3', 'key1']

ordered_dict = OrderedDict([('key4', 0), ('key1', 1), ('key2', 2), ('key0', 3), ('key3', 4)])

output = [v for v in ordered_dict if v in list_values]

print(output)
```

→

```
['key1', 'key3']
```

Example 2:

```
list_values = ['key3', 'key0', 'key1', 'key4', 'key2']

ordered_dict = OrderedDict([('key4', 0), ('key1', 1), ('key2', 2), ('key0', 3), ('key3', 4)])

output = [v for v in ordered_dict if v in list_values]

print(output)
```

→

```
['key4', 'key1', 'key2', 'key0', 'key3']
```